# Calling javascript function from flash cs3

Tags: javascript, html, flash

My javascript function from flash cs3 isn't getting called. The "test" alert at the top of the script is called so I know the javascript is working. The flash plays just fine so that's working. Below is the action script and the html. What am I missing?

as:

```
package
{
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class AnimatingObject extends MovieClip
    {

        // constants
        public const ANIMATION_COMPLETE:String = "animation_complete";

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function AnimatingObject()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameEnter);
        }

        /**
         * Called on dispatch of Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function frameEnter(e:Event):void
        {

            if(currentFrame == totalFrames)
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("stoppedPlaying");

                trace( "Event complete" );
                var evt:Event = new Event(ANIMATION_COMPLETE);
                dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("test");

        function stoppedPlaying(){
            alert("finished");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body width="100%" height="100%">
    <!--<embed src="dalogo.swf" width="100%" height="100%" quality="high">-->
    <object width="500" height="500">
        <param name="movie" value="dalogo.swf">
        <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <embed src="dalogo.swf" width="100" height="100">
        </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to add "allowScriptAcess" parameter to your embed code. Here is some more info: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/changes-allowscriptaccess-default-flash-player.html

Comment: What is this classid stuff? Where is that guid something from? <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" ... >

Comment: Updated the html in my question but still no event fired

Comment: In which browser do you run your html file? Try to upload both HTML and SWF files to the web server. Locally, the ExternalInterface will not works in GoogleChrome.

Comment: In Chrome locally. Why will it not work locally? Ultimately I'm trying to use this in Awesomium so it will be local, but testing it with Chrome.

Comment: I don't know why it will not work locally. Try to use another browser. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151667/externalinterface-in-chrome)